# Delete row in database (MySql and PHP )using form

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a problem . I create forms (usuw1.php) and (usuw2.php). But when i want delete row i got error message, that rows don't deleted. I don't know why, because my code is all right.. i guess. PLease help me.

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Usuwanie Rekordu</h2>
<form action="usuw2.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>ID:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ID" id="ID" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nacja:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Nacja" id="Nacja" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LiczbaPkt:</td>
      <td><input type ="text" name="LiczbaPkt"  id="LiczbaPkt"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="delete" type="submit" id="dodaj"
value="Usun Rekord"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

</body>
</html> 

<?php

// php code to Delete data from mysql database 

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $databaseName = "kluby ranking";

    // get id to delete
        $ID=$_POST["ID"];
        $Nacja=$_POST["Nacja"];
        $LiczbaPkt=$_POST["LiczbaPkt"]; 

    // connect to mysql
    $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

    // mysql delete query 
    $query = "DELETE FROM `europa` WHERE `ID ,Nacja, LiczbaPkt` = $ID,$Nacja,$LiczbaPkt";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    if($result)
    {
        echo 'Data Deleted';
    }else{
        echo 'Data Not Deleted';
    }
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
```

Comment: Try this `$query = "DELETE FROM europa WHERE ID=$ID and Nacja=$Nacja and LiczbaPkt = $LiczbaPkt";`

Comment: Unless you have a column called `ID ,Nacja, LiczbaPkt` mysql should throw errors at you... Also SQL injection hole...

Comment: If you added error checking - you may get useful information back, like your SQL syntax is incorrect.

Comment: using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  on your query? would have told you about that syntax error in your delete. RT!M http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/delete.html

Comment: PHP Expert thanks a lot , everything WORKS:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare more then 1 column to a bunch of results, you can't use EQUALS(=) sign . You can achieve this either by multiples conditions with `AND` or by using `IN` like this:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `europa` WHERE (`ID`,`Nacja`,`LiczbaPkt`) in ('$ID','$Nacja','$LiczbaPkt')"
```

Or with multiple conditions:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `europa` WHERE `ID` = '$ID' AND `Nacja` = '$Nanja' AND `LiczbaPkt` = '$LiczbaPkt'"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have error in this line
$query = "DELETE FROM `europa` WHERE `ID ,Nacja, LiczbaPkt` = $ID,$Nacja,$LiczbaPkt";

replace the above line to

$query = "DELETE FROM `europa` WHERE `ID`= '$ID' and `Nacja`='$Nacja' and `LiczbaPkt`='$LiczbaPkt' ";

Answer (score 0):

use this query

$query = "DELETE FROM `europa` WHERE ID = '$ID' AND Nacja = '$Nacja' AND  LiczbaPkt` = '$LiczbaPkt'";